# not getting all the fields from payload of JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, mean-stack

i have created a MEAN stack web app which has login logout option.for user to be logged in i have used jsonwebtoken npm package.
the main problem here is when user logs in a JWT is created and in that token's payload contain username,email and fullname but while decoding the token i am only getting username and email field

here is jwt.sign function-

```
var token=jwt.sign({userid:user.username,email:user.email,fullname:user.fullname},secret,{expiresIn:'24h'});
```

and here jwt.verify method-

```
jwt.verify(token,secret,function(err,decoded){
    if(err){
        res.json({success:false,message:"invalid token"});
    } else {
        req.decoded=decoded;
        next();
    }
})
```

token example-

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiJuaXRpbi5zYWNoZGV2IiwiZW1haWwiOiJuaXRpbi5zYWNoZGV2QGVtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTQ4NDU1ODAxMiwiZXhwIjoxNDg0NjQ0NDEyfQ.fWogT-aHJY4Xyc8Ebm4OXPkWD3poaWG3IAAf9VS-q58
```

token decoded-

```
{
    "userid": "nitin.sachdev",
    "email": "nitin.sachdev@email.com",
    "iat": 1484558012,
    "exp": 1484644412
}
```

userSchema -

```
 var UserSchema=new Schema({
    fullname:String,
    username:{type:String,lowercase:true,required:true,unique:true},
    password:{type:String,required:true},
    email:{type:String,required:true,lowercase:true,unique:true},
    contactno:Number,
    orgname:String
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the mistake,i forgot to enter fullname as a parameter in '.select()'method  while using '.findOne()' method to find user.

here is the corrected code-

```
                                                 //mistake was actually here    
User.findOne({username:req.body.username}).select('email username password fullname').exec(function(err,user){
                //if(err) throw err;
                if(!req.body.password||!req.body.username)
                {
                        res.json({success:false,mesage:"please enter all the fields"});

                }
                else
                {
                    if(!user){
                    res.json({success:false,message:"couldnt find the user"});
                }
                else if(user)
                {
                    if(!req.body.password)
                        res.json({success:false,mesage:"please enter password"});
                    var validPassword=user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
                    if(validPassword){
                        //jwt.sign ismethod to create JWT. 1st par is object containing data that token will contain.
                        console.log(user.fullname);
                        var token=jwt.sign({userid:user.username,email:user.email,fullname:user.orgname},secret,{expiresIn:'24h'});
                        res.json({success:true,message:"loggedin Successfully",token: token});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.json({success:false,message:"wrong password"});
                    }
                }   
                }

            });
```